# Or operator in selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get an alert when one of these checkboxes with classes `backCheckbox`, `backCheckbox2`, `backCheckbox3` are checked.

I tried something like this but not working:

```
$(['.badCheckbox'], ['.badCheckbox2'], ['.badCheckbox3']).change(function(){
    if(this.checked)
        alert("Bad checkbox!");
});
```

HTML:

```
<input class="badCheckbox" type="checkbox"/>
<input class="badCheckbox2" type="checkbox"/>
<input class="badCheckbox3" type="checkbox"/>
```

Comment: `$('.badCheckbox, .badCheckbox2, .badCheckbox3').change()`

Comment: Or just give them all a matching, second class...

Comment: or `$("input[class^='badCheckbox']")`

Comment: `$("input[type='checkbox'].change(function() {
    if($(this).checked) {
        alert("Bad checkbox!");
    } // always use braces
});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "or" operator in jQuery (CSS) selectors is the comma: `".classA, .id1, pre"`
You give jQuery a String, which is the selector as you would write it in CSS. It should be a single string, so only *one* set of quote marks, either `'` or `"`

```
$('.badCheckbox, .badCheckbox2, .badCheckbox3')
```

... but *classes* don't have to be unique, and in fact *shouldn't be*. What you have should use a unique *id* if you need to identify them individually, along with a common *class* — something like

```
<input id="badCheckbox1" class="badcheckbox" type="checkbox"/>
<input id="badCheckbox2" class="badcheckbox" type="checkbox"/>
<input id="badCheckbox3" class="badcheckbox" type="checkbox"/>
```

Then your jquery becomes

```
$('.badcheckbox').change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        alert("Bad checkbox!");
    } // always use braces
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Little question: Why are u using these brackets:
>   **[**`'.badCheckbox'`**]**`,`**[**`'.badCheckbox2'`**]**`,`**[**`'.badCheckbox3'`**]**?

Nevermind, you can select multiple elements in jQuery by adding a comma between everyone.
Here is an example:

`$(".firstClass, .secondClass, .thirdClass")`

So your code should be like this:

```
$(".badCheckbox, .badCheckbox2, .badCheckbox3").change(function(){
    if(this.checked)
        alert("Bad checkbox!");
});
```